# Qt: Is it possible to have indexed access for identical objects in a QDialog/QWindow?

Tags: qt, user-interface, object, indexing, dialog

I'm using Qt5 on Windows7 platform.
Using QtCreator I created the following QDialog:

[image]

Right now, the `QCheckBox`'es and `QTimeEdit`'s are, respectively:

```
- for Monday: checkBoxOpen1 and checkBoxClose1   
- for Monday: timeOpen1 and timeClose1   
- ...   
- for Sunday: checkBoxOpen7 and checkBoxClose7   
- for Sunday: timeOpen7 and timeClose7
```

And similar for all the objects in this QDialog interface.
It is quite difficult to work with it (cumbersome to get/set the properties/values for these objects...)

So, the question: Is there a way to provide some indexed access for all similar objects in the QDialog interface? (I hope to be able to keep somehow the facilities offered by QtDesigner...)

Comment: You can do so in your own program, I don't know any way doing this in qt Designer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create your widget, you can set its name by using:

```
void setObjectName(const QString & name)
```

Suppose all your widgets parent is `p`, then you can use:

```
QList<QWidget*> widgets = p.findChildren<QWidget*>("widgetname");
```

If you want to get all `QPushButton`, just use:

```
QList<QPushButton*> widgets = p.findChildren<QPushButton*>();
```

Comment: Combined your idea with some `QRegularExpression` and it did miracles! Probably there are also other tricks that do the job, yet this one has proved to be very good and quite efficient - only 4 lines of code and _voila_ the indexed access :) **Thx**!